# Unable to upload image and save to a folder using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-3.x

I am trying to upload the image in react, I used the extension ** react-image-upload**.
I used this code to show images on a webpage

```
import React from 'react';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { pictures: [] };
        this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
    }

    onDrop(pictureFiles, pictureDataURLs) {
        this.setState({
            pictures: pictureFiles
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ImageUploader
                withIcon={true}
                buttonText='Choose images'
                onChange={this.onDrop}
                imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                maxFileSize={5242880}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Now The image is showing on the webpage but I don't know how to upload it and save it to a folder I am trying to use this code.

1. This line is for onChange

```
   onDrop(pictureFiles, pictureDataURLs) {
        this.setState({
            picture: pictureFiles
        });
    }
```

2. This line is uploading the image, but I don't know how it will function and if I need to add the backend.

```
    uploadHandler = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.state.picture);
        console.log()

        let context = 'profile';
        service.uploadImage(formData,
            this.state.picture,
            context, (res) => {
                if (res.status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", res);
                    stopLoading();
                }
            });
    }
```

And the upload function -

```
export const uploadImage = (file, fileName, context, onDone) => {
    console.log(fileName)
    post(encodeURI("/api/upload-files/" + fileName  + "/" + context), file, (res) => {
        onDone(res.data);
    });
};
```

And the backend code, I am using FastAPI- Python for it-

```
@router.post("/upload-files")
async def image(image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(image.filename)
    return {"filename": image.filename}
```

I checked the values and the results are right on backend but on webpage it is showing 422: preprocessing error.
Please give some idea what's the process or some hint so I can complete the code.

Comment: Please let me know if you see any detail missing, thank you.

Comment: You don't have a backend to receive the uploads?

Comment: call `uploadHandler` in your `onDrop` method, and pass the relevant file to the `uploadHandler` instead of storing it in your react state.

Comment: @seesharper no, actually I am new to frontend and dont know much about to how to develop backend code

Comment: Obviously, nothing is going to happen without a server to upload to! As far as your code goes though, it looks like the main thing that is missing is something to trigger the upload after you drop the files there. I had a quick look at the component you are using. Honestly if it were me I'd use something else - the developer is considering archiving it and it's not compatible with latest React.

Comment: @seesharper thank you, I added the backend code and on backend it is showing the result but on react side, the error is 422: preprocessing error

Comment: What do you mean "showing the result"? Does the image upload? The 422 error suggests it doesn't  - it means the server did not like the format of the data sent to it.

Comment: It shows the result on: localhost:8000/docs

Comment: Yes, I can download it on the backend